# Change behavior of superscript key in text editor (elementary os)

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, dead-keys

When writing latex in sublime text is often use the `^` character to insert superscript. right now the default behavior is quite annoying, as it does not insert the `^` until i press `space`. How change i change this, so it will always insert `^` right away?

I use Elementary OS Luna with a Danish keyboard layout. The shortcut to insert `^` is `shift+^`

Comment: This is probably due to your keyboard layout, that depends on "dead" keys to generate accented letters, so hitting <kbd>^</kbd> followed by <kbd>o</kbd> will probably generate ô. If you don't need that (or any other "special" letters) I suggest you switch to the US keybaord layout.

Comment: I don't need letter like ô. But I have a Danish keyboard and I use the Danish letters æ,ø,å a lot, but almost never ô and alike. So changing keyboard layout is not really an option.

Answer (score 1):

To modify your Danish keyboard layout to not use the "dead" key for circumflex, you can use this command:

```
$ xmodmap -e 'keycode 15 = 6 asciicircum'
```

To restore it you can use:

```
$ xmodmap -e 'keycode 15 = 6 dead_circumflex'
```

(Don't ask me why the former uses `asciicircum` instead of the expected `circumflex`...)

Put the command in the appropriate startup script for your desktop (I use `fvwm` and have such commands in my `~/.xsession`; I use the same setup for the last 20 years :-) ).

Comment: I did not work for me. The behavior did not change.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the keyboard layout to `Danish (eliminate dead keys)` did the trick.